# GET id corrosponding to the item in list view

Tags: android

```
public class Chanel_Display extends Activity {

    // List view
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;

    // ArrayList for Listview

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chanel__display);

        // Listview Data


        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,
                R.id.product_name, MainActivity.outlets);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                Chanel_Display.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here i write above code to display Listview.It works fine Can i use HashMap insted of array.Because i need to get the id of the clicked item.In my code i can only get the value.All i want to do is to take id of the item (it is a string) of List view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need id or the item? If you need id you can use `lv.getItemIdAtPosition(position)` and if you need the item you can use `lv.getItemAtPosition(position)`.